# Remove a buddy in Finch

Tags: instant-messaging, pidgin, finch

Is there a way to remove a buddy from my buddy list in Finch? If it matters, I'm using Jabber, and the buddy list looks like it is stored server side (editing blist.xml did not work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click the buddy (or press <kbd>F11</kbd>), then select "Remove" (<kbd>r</kbd>).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I don't have mouse support enabled for finch, and F11 just makes my terminal full-screen. Is there some way to escape F11 and send it through?

Comment: Jeff: Try `Esc` `[` `2` `3` `~` for the F11 key, or follow [these instructions](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Finch#enable-mouse).

Comment: Escape sequence didn't seem to work for me (guessing it's terminal specific), but now my mouse is working! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> will also work as a right click or <kbd>F11</kbd>.